# Yii2 GridView with Kartik Select2 as filter shows only once

Tags: filter, gridview, yii2, jquery-select2

I have a standard Yii2 GridView and want to use in two different grid columns Kartic Select2 widget as filter. But it will be shown only once in one column. In the second column the filter will be empty.

[image]

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'facility_id',
            'value' => 'facility.name',
            'filter' => Select2::widget([
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'attribute' => 'facility_id',
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Facility::find()->where('client_id = ' . $client->id)->orderBy('id DESC')->all(), 'id', 'name'),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => ''],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'width' => 'element',
                ],
            ]),
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'client_push_mail_id',
            'value' => 'clientPushMail.name',
            'filter' => Select2::widget([
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'attribute' => 'client_push_mail_id',
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(ClientPushMail::find()->where('client_id = ' . $client->id)->orderBy('id DESC')->all(), 'id', 'name'),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => ''],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'width' => 'element',
                ],
            ]),
        ],
```

Inspecting the DOM:
both columns have the dropdown markup (<select id="...>) but the second column is missing the select2-container (<span class="select2 select2-container...>).

[image]

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it: you have to define 'id' and 'name' with different values in options of the widget:

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'facility_id',
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 200px;'],
            'value' => 'facility.name',
            'filter' => Select2::widget([
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'attribute' => 'facility_id',
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Facility::find()->where('client_id = ' . $client->id)->orderBy('id DESC')->all(), 'id', 'name'),
                'options' => [
                    'id' => '123',
                    'name' => 'abc',
                    'placeholder' => ''
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true,
                    'width' => 'element',
                ],
            ]),
        ],
```